# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. use kubernetes executor

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I used EKS, Below is the eks information：

```bash
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.5", GitCommit:"aea7bbadd2fc0cd689de94a54e5b7b758869d691", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-09-15T21:10:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21+", GitVersion:"v1.21.14-eks-6d3986b", GitCommit:"8877a3e28d597e1184c15e4b5d543d5dc36b083b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-07-20T22:05:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Gitlab use `gitlab/gitlab-ce:14.1.8-ce.0` image, and gitlab-runner use helm chat 0.46.0 [15.5.0] version:

```yaml
image:
  registry: registry.gitlab.com
  image: gitlab-org/gitlab-runner
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
replicas: 4
gitlabUrl: 'https://git.xxx.xxx/'
runnerRegistrationToken: xxxxxxxxxxx
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 3600
concurrent: 10
checkInterval: 30
sessionServer:
  enabled: false
rbac:
  create: true
  rules: []
  clusterWideAccess: false
  podSecurityPolicy:
    enabled: false
    resourceNames:
      - gitlab-runner
metrics:
  enabled: false
  portName: metrics
  port: 9252
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: false
service:
  enabled: false
  type: ClusterIP
runners:
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      [runners.kubernetes]
        namespace = "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
        image = "ubuntu:16.04"
        privileged = true
        [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.host_path]]
          name = "docker"
          mount_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
          read_only = false
          host_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
        [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.host_path]]
          name = "dockerlib"
          mount_path = "/var/lib/docker"
          read_only = false
          host_path = "/var/lib/docker"
  requestConcurrency: 10
  privileged: true
  cache: {}
  builds: {}
  services: {}
  helpers: {}
securityContext:
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
  runAsNonRoot: true
  privileged: false
  capabilities:
    drop:
      - ALL
podSecurityContext:
  runAsUser: 100
  fsGroup: 65533
resources: {}
affinity: {}
nodeSelector: {}
tolerations: []
hostAliases: []
podAnnotations: {}
podLabels: {}
priorityClassName: ''
secrets: []
configMaps: {}
volumeMounts: []
volumes: []
```

Then I used a simple `.gitlab-ci.yaml` to test:

```yaml
variables:
  HARBOR_HOST: "harbor.xxx.xxx"
  HARBOR_USERNAME: "devops"
  HARBOR_PASSWORD: "xxx"
  PROJECT_NAME: "test"

stages:
  - clone
  - build_project
  - build_image
  - push_image

.clone_project:
  stage: clone
  only:
    - master
    - test
    - main
    - staging
  script:
    - pwd
    - ls -l

build_image:
  stage: build_image
  image: docker:20.10.16
  services:
    - name: docker:20.10.16-dind
      alias: docker
      command: ["--tls=false"]
  variables:
    # DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    # DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true"
  before_script:
    - echo ${HARBOR_PASSWORD} |  docker login -u ${HARBOR_USERNAME} --password-stdin ${HARBOR_HOST}
  script:
    - ls 
    - pwd 
    - ls -l /var/run
    - ls /var/run
    - ps aux
    - docker images
```

Below is the result after execution：

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.5.0 (0d4137b8)
  on gitlab-runner-8f78fb7f4-tzdkz 6bdCkzUP
  feature flags: FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD:true
Preparing the "kubernetes" executor
00:00
Using Kubernetes namespace: devops
Using Kubernetes executor with image docker:20.10.16 ...
Using attach strategy to execute scripts...
Preparing environment
00:04
Waiting for pod devops/runner-6bdckzup-project-131-concurrent-0bzq9b to be running, status is Pending
Running on runner-6bdckzup-project-131-concurrent-0bzq9b via gitlab-runner-8f78fb7f4-tzdkz...
Getting source from Git repository
00:00
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/weex-ops/weexcli/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out d05f3469 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
$ echo ${HARBOR_PASSWORD} |  docker login -u ${HARBOR_USERNAME} --password-stdin ${HARBOR_HOST}
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
$ ls
HelpClass.py
KsNotifyWebhook
README.md
__pycache__
blocks.json
log__3_.txt
requirements.txt
slack
weexcli.py
$ pwd
/builds/weex-ops/weexcli
$ ls -l /var/run
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             4 May 23 16:51 /var/run -> /run
$ ls /var/run
docker.sock
secrets
$ ps aux
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /bin/sh
   10 root      0:00 /bin/sh /scripts-131-68/step_script
   11 root      0:00 tee -a /logs-131-68/output.log
   15 root      0:00 /bin/sh /scripts-131-68/step_script
   31 root      0:00 ps aux
$ docker images
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

I checked the official documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#using-docker-in-your-builds, but it doesn't seem to work for me

I've been here for too long and I hope someone can help me.

And I tried kaniko, but still got a problem that I can't solve：

```
variables:
  HARBOR_HOST: "harbor.x.xxx"
  HARBOR_USERNAME: "robot$xxx"
  HARBOR_PASSWORD: "xxx"

stages:
  - build_project

build_image:
  stage: build_image
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.9.1-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"${HARBOR_HOST}\":{\"auth\":\"$(printf "%s:%s" "${HARBOR_USERNAME}" "${HARBOR_PASSWORD}" | base64 | tr -d '\n')\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - cat /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - echo ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
    - echo ${CI_COMMIT_TAG}
    - echo ${HARBOR_HOST}
    - /kaniko/executor
      --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
      --dockerfile "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Dockerfile"
      --destination "${HARBOR_HOST}:/ops/abcli:tag"
```

The result:

```
$ /kaniko/executor --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}" --dockerfile "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Dockerfile" --destination "${HARBOR_HOST}:/ops/abcli:tag"
error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: checking push permission for "harbor.xxx.xxx:/ops/abcli:tag": POST https://harbor.xxx.xxx/v2/ops/abcli/blobs/uploads/: UNAUTHORIZED: unauthorized to access repository: ops/abcli, action: push: unauthorized to access repository: ops/abcli, action: push
```

I tried to use `echo -n ${HABOR_USER}:${HARBOR_PASSWORD} | base64` directly, and then replace the `auth` field, but still have the same problem.

Comment: the docker login command work, but some reason it not able to connect with docker daemon,  so seems like sound this `I find that if you sleep for say 30 seconds before running Docker commands, then this does not happen. It could be that the container svc-0 (using dind) for docker has not started completely and is not ready?`

Comment: thanks，I tried adding `sleep 30` to `before_script`, but the result is still the same.`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375`

Comment: btw my experience docker in docker is gitlab is always suck , i will suggest to use kaniko that does not need docker in docker, docker in docker also expose much security risk

Comment: in the past, for similar issue `docker:19.03.12-dind` this version worked for me

Comment: which version of docker is running in the host node?

Comment: @Adiii thanks, In the past I was able to use docker:17.03, but now I can't; I tested it in EKS, I can't check the docker version information on the node; I am not familiar with kaniko

Comment: @JasonTom did you managed to get this working? I'm having the same problem. Have tried different configurations for gitlab runner and different versions of k8s on eks, but getting same error all the time. GitLab docs is not that helpful either.